# Symfony Doctrine Flush Entity

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity SourceElanceProfileImport, and I create this entity in action and set some data and when I flush have error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies\__CG__\Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Teams could not be converted to string
```

and question, why if I find teams like this I have Proxies object

```
$team = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Teams')->findOneById($id);
```

I tra hard code write id and have nor entity Teams

```
$id = '2';
$team = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Teams')->findOneById($id);
// $team entity Teams, not Proxies
```

what’s happened not right in this action?

action:

```
   public function elanceProfileAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $url = $request->get('url');
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $firstName = $request->get('firstName');

    $user = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Users')->getCompanyByEmail($request->get('email'));
    $id = $user[0]->getTeams()->getId();
    $team = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Teams')->findOneById($id);
    if (!empty($user)) {
        $elance_import = new SourceElanceProfileImport();

        $hepler = $this->container->get('artel.profile.additional_function');
        $pass = $hepler->generatePassword();
        $elance_import
            ->setEmail($email)
            ->setSecurityHash(sha1($pass))
            ->setElanceUrl($url)
            ->setTeamId($team)
            ;
        $em->persist($elance_import);
        $em->flush();
```

and entity:

```
class SourceElanceProfileImport
{
/**
 * @var \Teams
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Teams")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 * })
 */
private $teamId;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="team_id", type="integer")
 */
public $team;
```

when I add __toString to entity Teams I have:

```
    public function __toString()
{
    return $this->company;
}

Error in one or more bulk request actions:

index: /aog/sourceelanceprofileimport/5 caused MapperParsingException[failed to parse [team_id]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "Gutkowski LLC"];
```

why in another entity work fine, what’s wrong I don’t know ((

**update** 
I solved but I think this is solved not fine and that’s one I don’t delete this question
I add in User entity:

```
    private function _load()
{
    // lazy loading code
}

/**
 * Get teams
 *
 * @return \Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Teams
 */
public function getLoadTeams()
{
    $this->_load();
    return parent::getId();
}
```

and in my action

```
        $user = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Users')->getCompanyByEmail($request->get('email'));
    $id = $user[0]->getLoadTeams();
    $team = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Teams')->findOneById($id);
```

than I have object Teams in variable $team, **BUT** when I flush I still have error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Teams could not be converted to string
```

Comment: Is it normal that $teamId requires Entity Team and $team requires a Id ?

Comment: maybe norm, because for another entity work fine. I just add field for another entity Teams and not create inversedBy field for entity Teams

Comment: I've been using symphony for a little bit now and Ive experiienced it being not as type-free as php is by itself. In that edit you just made where you hardcode the $id, I'm pretty sure you can't let it be a string when you search on a field that is in fact an integer.

Comment: but its is true when I do this '$id = '2';$team = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Teams')->findOneById($id);// $team entity Teams, not Proxies'

Answer (score 0):

I solved, but problem it was in persist entity and in config fos_elastic
I still have Proxies Teams entity but in action

```
        $user = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Users')->getCompanyByEmail($request->get('email'));
    $id = $user[0]->getTeams()->getId();
    $team = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Teams')->findOneById($id);

    if (!empty($user)) {
        $elance_import = new SourceElanceProfileImport();

        $hepler = $this->container->get('artel.profile.additional_function');
        $pass = $hepler->generatePassword();
        $elance_import
            ->setEmail($email)
            ->setSecurityHash(sha1($pass))
            ->setElanceUrl($url);
        $em->persist($elance_import);
        $elance_import->setTeamId($team);

        $em->flush();
```

and flush fine entity create and have id Teams  (Proxies object Teams)
and teamId this is relationship with entity Teams and in fos_elastica need write like this:

```
                sourceelanceprofileimport:
                mappings:
                    id:
                      type: integer
                    elance_url:
                      type: string
                    full_name:
                      type: string
                    status:
                      type: string
                    created:
                      type: date
                    approved_at:
                      type: date
                    imported_at:
                      type: date
                    team_id:
                        type: "nested"
                        properties:
                            id: ~
                persistence:
                    # the driver can be orm, mongodb or propel
                    # listener and finder are not supported by
                    # propel and should be removed
                    driver: orm
                    model: Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\SourceElanceProfileImport
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~
```

and I have entity in my DB and Elastic DB

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have proxies every time an entity is not completely populated. Proxies are used to return partial entities.
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html

Looking your code I noticed this:

```
$team = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Teams')->findOneById($id);
```

But you can do the same in this way:

```
$team = $em->find('ArtelProfileBundle:Teams', $id); // EntityManager::find has 2 arguments: entity and id.
```

Underneath you do this:

```
$user = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Users')->getCompanyByEmail($request->get('email'));
```

Did you implement some custom code on getCompanyByEmail? If not, you can use Doctrine's methods:

```
$user = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Users')->findOneByEmail($request->get('email'));
```

Those are magic methods: findOneBy or findBy. One returns a single object or NULL, the other one returns an array with results.
You can also do this:

```
$user = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Users')->findOneBy(['email' => $request->get('email')]); // you can add more key/value filters on the array
```

Now just to be sure, did you implement APC as bytecode cache? Because when I make changes on my entities I usually need to flush APC (restarting the webserver) to force the cache to regenerate it. If misterious errors occur maybe APC should be restarted.

Now, regarding the flush error, did you implement a __toString method on any entity? Probably it's not returning a string.

Comment: function getCompanyByEmail tjis is custom query  builder